# WPF notify icon databinding not working

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, notifyicon

I am using wpf notifyicon from this project:
[Codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon?msg=4649470#xx4649470xx)

I am having an issue while binding selectedItem of a listbox in popup with the viewmodel. Also, the tootip text background is black. please help me. i m having great trouble with the binding issue.

Below is a code snippet:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AppModules}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModule, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The listbox gets populated as expected, but the selected item binding is not working. Please help.

Comment: are you getting any exception in output window?

Comment: not really, i found the issue, actually, i was using a control template for listboxitems which is a button in place of listboxitems. Now, when the button gets clicked, the bounded command gets fired, but selected item not changes. any idea how to do that?

Comment: can you send the commandparameter as CommandParameter = {Binding}. This should be the selected item. You can set the SelectedItem in the command handler

Comment: if it solves your problem. can you update the question so that others so it can be used by others also. Thanks